# How to copy files with scp to an ec2 instace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

i am trying to copy files to an EC2 instance with the scp command as follows:

```
scp -i "key-pair-name.pem" somefile.txt ec2xxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

I get the following error: 
    Permission denied (publickey).
    lost connection

I am using an amazon linux machine

I am able to ssh just fine.
I've gone over Q&A here, with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried add slash to the end of your command?    `scp -i "key-pair-name.pem" somefile.txt ec2xxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~/`

Comment: On Ubuntu images for example the username that has the `.pem` key is the user `ubuntu`, thus `ubuntu@ec2...yadayada...` or `-l ubuntu`

Comment: @sergiy.dragunov and that is not the problem, the command fails *before* the path is actually interpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the username, eg:

```
scp -i "key-pair-name.pem" somefile.txt user@ec2xxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

Comment: i got the user name on the ec2 instace via the "whoami" command. Now i tried:  scp -i avicohen2480.pem stam.txt ec2user@ec2xxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~/